# Multiple Dropbox accounts on the same IP?

Tags: dropbox

I use Dropbox a lot and I have everything organized. My friends and my 2 brothers would like to use the application too.

The problem is that my brothers and me are on the same network. And it could be that my friends PCs have been previously used in Dropbox.

My brothers have a different PC. But on the same IP. If they create an account and download the application on their PC will this risk my account?

And can I use them as referral?

Comment: Nope. That's not how the Internet works.  Dropbox is installation specific, so two user accounts on the same computer can even sync their Dropbox simultaneously.

Comment: @digitxp: It's not about how Internet works, but rather about how Dropbox servers work (for example, IP address checks to prevent "gaming the referral system").

Comment: @grawity Whoops. I've been spending way too much time studying network security.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no problem with multiple Dropbox accounts on the same network. I can't imagine Dropbox being popular in companies and schools if this was the case. However, there are ways you can run multiple Dropbox accounts/clients on the same computer. See: [Dropboxen](http://wiki.dropbox.com/DropboxAddons/Dropboxen)

Yes, they can sign up using your referral link and earn the extra storage.

Comment: I just wanted to be 100% sure.. Thanks for the quick answer

Comment: @Jin, Dropboxen link appears to be dead.  http://new.dropboxwiki.com/dropbox-addons/dropboxen?title=Dropboxen works